# Using for loop to output equations in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I currently have a series of equations that I'm using to model compartments of a biological system. I want to be able to set a variable, n, outside of the for-loop for the number of compartments I want the model to have, then have the function output that many dn.dt's. I'm pretty sure I have to return them as a vector at the end of the function, but that's the only lead I have. Below is what I want my basic function to be for when n = 3.

```
rate <- function(time, state, parms){
  with(as.list(c(state,parms)),{
    dX.dt <- do stuff
    d1.dt <- do different stuff 
    d2.dt <- do same stuff as d1.dt
    d3.dt <- do same stuff as d1.dt
    return(list(c(dX.dt, d1.dt, d2.dt, d3.dt)))})}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You question is not particularly clear at the moment. When you say `do the same stuff as d1.dt`. Is this something random that will change, or is it doing something with a different set of `state` and `parms`. I think what  you are looking for is `replicate`, and will post an answer if that is the case

Comment: Yes, d1.dt through dn.dt will all preform the same function with the same state and parms. I just didn't want to type out excess code that was irrelevant to the main question. The only difference between the different equations in the system will be that dX.dt will be a combination of the other compartments. For example:
dX.dt <- a*1 + b*2 + c*3 - d*1 - e*2 - f*3

Compartment X is essentially how all the other compartments interact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after `replicate`, you can pass `n` as the number of replicates required.

```
rate <- function(time, state, parms, n){

  dX.dt <- with(as.list(c(state,parms)), foo(....))
  dn.dt <-  with(as.list(c(state,parms)), replicate(n, foobar(...), simplify = FALSE)

return(c(dX.dt, dn.t))))}
```

I'm not sure about the `with(as.list(c(state,parms))` are necessary, but without a simple reproducible example, I can't be sure.

Comment: They are functions that will `do stuff` as per your pseudocode (you will need to define them)